# Entire functions on two nonparallel lines belongs to $L^2(-\infty,\infty)$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Suppose that $f$ is an entire function of exponential type. If its restriction on two nonparallel lines belongs to $L^2(-\infty,\infty)$, show that $f=0$. I am sorry that I don't how to write the first line of a proof. Can anyone give me some advice? Thanks!

Comment: By Paley Wiener theorem it follows that $f$ is bounded (that can be proved directly also by subharmonicity arguments, fairly straightforward- see any book on entire functions eg Boas chapter 6) on the two non-parallel-lines and then by Phragmen-Lindelof, $f$ bounded hence constant hence zero

Comment: @ Conrad, why Paley-Wiener theorem implies that $f$ is bounded?

Comment: Paley wiener ($f$ square integrable on the real line) implies that $f$ has an integral representation $\int_{-A}^Ae^{itz}g(t)dt$ and $g$ is integrable so $f$ is bounded on any horizontal line; apply this to the two non-parallel lines of the hypothesis getting $f$ bounded on those lines; phragmen lindelof gives $f$ bounded in the plane since $f$ has order $1$

Comment: @ Conrad, I see the point now. Thanks so much for your explanation.

Comment: Happy to help - paley wiener is a heavy tool and the boundness result obtained from it can be deduced directly by straightforward manipulations with subharmonic functions ($\log |f|$) but they are tedious; actually one can prove even that $|f| \to 0$ at infinity on the horizontal lines where the function is square integrable